# How to import Aptana plugins in my personal Eclipse platform?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have an Eclipse platform that is personalized for my java and android programming, but while I'm working with Android and Java, I need to develop web programs, and It bother me to run to Eclipse platform, one is my personal Eclipse another is Aptana!
Is there any way to combine Aptana and Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to the [Aptana download site](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download), they give the options for both  Stand-alone and Plug-in versions. The directions appear to be simple.